# How to proceed after the Google Authentication in ios App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-authentication

How to proceed after the Google Authentication in ios App? When i allow the access for my application. The window appear is "Please copy this code,switch to your application and copy it there:".I dont know how to proceed from here.
This is the code i write

```
SEL finishedSel = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);

viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch 
                                     controllerWithScope:scope
                                      clientID:clientID
                                      clientSecret:clientSecret
                                      keychainItemName:nil
                                      delegate:self                                                     finishedSelector:finishedSel]autorelease];


-(void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Authentication failed
    } else {
        // Authentication succeeded
    }
}
```

Comment: do u get ur solution....for ur post

Answer (score 4):

after getting the authentication
you can use it to get user data, see this code

```
 NSString *urlStr = @"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [self.auth authorizeRequest:request
              completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                  NSString *output = nil;
                  if (error) {
                      output = [error description];
                  } else {
                      // Synchronous fetches like this are a really bad idea in Cocoa applications
                      //
                      // For a very easy async alternative, we could use GTMHTTPFetcher
                      NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                      NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                           returningResponse:&response
                                                                       error:&error];
                      if (data) {
                          // API fetch succeeded
                          output = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

                          NSLog(@"output:%@",output);


                      } else {
                          // fetch failed
                          output = [error description];
                      }
                  }

              }];
```

note you need to add this url in scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

Answer (score 0):

check this link [gtm-oauth2](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/)

and here is a sample code of finishedWithAuth

```
(void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error {
      if (error != nil) {
          // Authentication failed (perhaps the user denied access, or closed the
          // window before granting access)
          NSLog(@"Authentication error: %@", error);
          NSData *responseData = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"]; // kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDataKey
          if ([responseData length] > 0) {
              // show the body of the server's authentication failure response
              NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
              NSLog(@"%@", str);
          }
          self.auth = nil;
      } else {
          // Authentication succeeded
          //
          // At this point, we either use the authentication object to explicitly
          // authorize requests, like
          //
          //  [auth authorizeRequest:myNSURLMutableRequest
          //       completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
          //         if (error == nil) {
          //           // request here has been authorized
          //         }
          //       }];
          //
          // or store the authentication object into a fetcher or a Google API service
          // object like
          //
          //   [fetcher setAuthorizer:auth];
          // save the authentication object
          self.auth = auth;
      }
}
```

Comment: But how to give next api request and get the data? that is the issue where i stuck.

Comment: @ajith Same problem here, I logged the downloadedData_ in the GTMHTTPFetcher.m and I get the access_token, token_type, expires_in, id_token, refresh_token, id, email, verified_email. I don't get the data I like to have. I like to access the AdSense data, I set the scope to adsense, so the problem isn't the scope. Did you find a fix yet?

Comment: @mahmoud iphase one prblm. first time i logged in G+ and second time i get one Recieve error..Received error (null) and auth object GTMOAuth2Authentication 0x884c920: {accessToken="ya29.AHES6ZQcL6Z1tBymq-8Zd_YSsm1aH81UQ3eET4vHUndzRX0JkHJNaQ", refreshToken="1/4HFOjk6S84wCTYoFmwqgPd0S8em7Fqg4-y4xsQZCRgk", expirationDate="2013-08-19 12:11:43 +0000"} so plz help me